# Python FormAlchemy helpers select tag

Tags: python, formalchemy

I have recently updated FormAlchemy to the newest version 1.5.3.

Up to now my select tags were created like this:

```
helpers.select(self.name, value, variants, class_="form-control")
```

where variants is a list e.g.:

```
['created', 'edited', 'published', 'rejected', 'unpublished']
```

and were working fine.

After the update all my selects contains **only first two options** with reversed order.

The source code of helpers.py (https://github.com/FormAlchemy/formalchemy/blob/master/formalchemy/helpers.py) shows in the line 185 it is a correct behaviour (at least according to the code I can see there). **But why?** What should I do to display all my options again?

Answer (score 0):

Lists and tuples are not allowed as a select options anymore. 
It must be a dictionary of value:index pairs.

This additional line will do the job:

```
variants = dict((el,index) for index,el in enumerate(variants))
```